# Android : MPAndroidChart how to remove values on right side in chart?

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I have the following chart which is displaying some values.

I would like to hide/ remove values on the right side, because on the left side are enough.

See image below:

[image]

**And code is following:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        OnChartValueSelectedListener{
    private LineChart mDataLineChart;
    private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;

    private LineChart mChart;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_linechart);

        // Set chart
        setChart();
        // add data
        setData2(3, 155);
        // ANIMATE CHART
        animateChart();
    }


    private void setChart() {
        mChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
        mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);

        ////////////////////////////////
        // SET DESCRIPTION COLOR
        ////////////////////////////////
        mChart.setDescriptionColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.chart_desc_color));
        ////////////////////////////////
        // BORDERS SURROUNDING THE CHART
        ////////////////////////////////
        mChart.setDrawBorders(true);
        mChart.setBorderColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.chart_border));
        mChart.setBorderWidth(2);
        ////////////////////////////////
        // CHART BG COLOR
        ////////////////////////////////
        mChart.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.chart_bg));
        ////////////////////////////////
        // GRID BG COLOR
        ////////////////////////////////
        mChart.setDrawGridBackground(true);
        mChart.setGridBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.chart_bg));

        ////////////////////////////////
        // OTHER SETTINGS
        ////////////////////////////////
        mChart.setDescription("");
        mChart.setNoDataTextDescription("You need to provide data for the chart.");
        // enable touch gestures
        mChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
        mChart.setDragDecelerationFrictionCoef(0.9f);
        // enable scaling and dragging
        mChart.setDragEnabled(true);
        mChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
        mChart.setHighlightPerDragEnabled(true);
        // if disabled, scaling can be done on x- and y-axis separately
        mChart.setPinchZoom(true);

    }


    private void setData2(int count, float range) {

        ////////////////////////////////
        // X axis values (labels)
        ////////////////////////////////
        ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            xVals.add((i) + " day");
        }

        ////////////////////////////////
        // Y axis values (value in linechart)
        ////////////////////////////////
        ArrayList<Entry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            float mult = range / 2f;
            float val = (float) (Math.random() * mult) + 50;// + (float)
            // ((mult *
            // 0.1) / 10);
            yVals1.add(new Entry(val, i));
        }

        ////////////////////////////////
        // SETTING FOR LINEAR LINE
        ////////////////////////////////
        LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(yVals1, "Pressure mm/Hg");
        set1.setAxisDependency(AxisDependency.LEFT);
        set1.setLineWidth(2f);
        set1.setCircleSize(5f);
        set1.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.chart_line_color));
        set1.setCircleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.chart_line_color));
        set1.setFillColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.chart_line_color));
        set1.setDrawCircleHole(true);

        ArrayList<LineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<LineDataSet>();
        dataSets.add(set1); // add the datasets

        ////////////////////////////////
        // SETTING FOR DATASET (FONT SIZE, )
        ////////////////////////////////
        LineData data = new LineData(xVals, dataSets);
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        data.setValueTextSize(9f);

        ////////////////////////////////
        // SET WHOLE DATASET TO CHART
        ////////////////////////////////
        mChart.setData(data);
    }

    private void animateChart() {
        ////////////////////////////////
        // ANIMATION DURATION
        ////////////////////////////////
        mChart.animateX(1000);
        ////////////////////////////////
        // SET LEGEND BOTTOM DATA TEXT
        ////////////////////////////////
        XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setTextSize(12f);
        xAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setSpaceBetweenLabels(1);



    }

    @Override
    public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
        Log.i("Entry selected", e.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected() {
        Log.i("Nothing selected", "Nothing selected.");
    }

}
```

I tried to search in documentation on Github:

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-Axis

But without luck.

How can i remove values from right please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 23):

```
YAxis yAxisRight = mChart.getAxisRight();
yAxisRight.setEnabled(false);
```

put this code on your setChart();

Answer (score -1):

You may want to check example application and corresponding codes. The application includes 2 related examples: Line Chart and Line Chart (Dual YAxis). The first is what you want and the latter is what you have right know.

App link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xxmassdeveloper.mpchartexample

Code: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/master/MPChartExample

Comment: The problem is because you create the chart by creating 2 Y-axis, one for left, one for right. You don't need the right one. Try to remove the one with yVals2 and add only the first one to the chart.

Comment: I dont work with yVals2, it was commented code. I updated code sample.

Comment: Could You please to provide updated example. Which is displaying only values on left side of the chart?